# Set up to resolve local ips

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2, bind

I have an apache with following settings.

```
192.168.0.105:8080/site1
192.168.0.105:8080/site2
and,
192.168.0.103/blog
```

I have 3 other computers in my network. 2 desktops and a laptop.

On every computer, on the browser I want to type some thing like,

```
example.com/site --> resolve to 192.168.0.105:8080/site1
example.com/site --> resolve to 192.168.0.105:8080/site2
```

and,

```
sample.com/blog --> resolve to 192.168.0.103/blog
```

I want 2 names......example.com and sample.com and I just want it to resolve these addresses for every computer on the network. I dont want it to cache public domain names for local use nor have outside internet access these sites.  The above apache is running on a ubuntu 9.04 VM, and I assigned the IPS.

I am following this guide there. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=236093

I am having issues with zone definition and reverse zone definition files. I dont really understand the options. Can some one tell me which options to change to suit my particular case....

```
// replace example.com with your domain name. do not forget the . after the domain name!
// Also, replace ns1 with the name of your DNS server
example.com.      IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
// Do not modify the following lines!
                                                        2006081401
                                                        28800
                                                        3600
                                                        604800
                                                        38400
 )

// Replace the following line as necessary:
// ns1 = DNS Server name
// mta = mail server name
// example.com = domain name
example.com.      IN      NS              ns1.example.com.
example.com.      IN      MX     10       mta.example.com.

// Replace the IP address with the right IP addresses.
www              IN      A       192.168.0.2
mta              IN      A       192.168.0.3
ns1              IN      A       192.168.0.1
```

and the reverse zone definition file,

```
//replace example.com with yoour domain name, ns1 with your DNS server name.
// The number before IN PTR example.com is the machine address of the DNS server. in my     case, it's 1, as my IP address is 192.168.0.1.
@ IN SOA ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                        20060;
                        28800; 
                        604800;
                        604800;
                        86400 
)

                     IN    NS     ns1.example.com.
1                    IN    PTR    example.com
```

I am just confused and I'd rather have a clearer understanding of what I am doing than trying a bunch of things. Any help would be great.... Also, please let me know if I am not doing some thing right. Thanks for your time.

Comment: +1 for a polite, well-formed and well-illustrated question.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but have you configured your LAN machines to ask for DNS resolution from that bind server you set up?

Comment: If this is only for a few hosts on your local network you might be much better off with something more light-weight like Dnsmasq instead of messing with bind.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, which sounds like a LAN development case, I would take the easy road and just edit the `/etc/hosts` file on your three local machines to resolve to your LAN development server, rather than going through the rigmarole of configuring `bind` on your LAN.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 

192.168.0.103   sample.com
192.168.0.105   example.com
```

You'll still get example.com/site1 and /site2 because they're handled by Apache.

The only caveat is that you will have to have the **user add the port** to the request because you can't specify destination ports in `/etc/hosts`, or you could use a couple of the simple options available to you through `iptables` and `vhosts.conf`.

I'm also assuming this would be an acceptable solution because you said "I just want it to resolve these addresses for [three| computer[s] on the network" and not *I want to learn how to configure bind properly*.